# Handling null values while extracting using java from MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, nullpointerexception, database

Frequently, I extract the data from mongo database using java (because I have to do it across very large number of collection across many databases). In the process, I generally use

Eg:

```
time = ((myObject.containsField("time"))) ? (myObject.get("time").toString().isEmpty()) ? "Empty" : myObject.get("time").toString() : "NA";
```

to make sure if the string exists or it is empty. but how do we do a null check, I mean if time has a value null

Eg: `time=null`

How do we extract the value to script so that I can save it to the extract as some string which represents null value?

`.get` is resulting in to a `NullPointerException`. This is a run time check and I often extract more than 20 values for each record. What is the best way to do a null check?

your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: Do you want the resulting time to be a String `"null"` or `null`

Comment: I want it to be racta string "null". so that I can save it as a value of time for a record

Comment: Ok, then the below answer should work for you.

Comment: it is not working patrick

Comment: Need to find out where the NPE is actually coming from then... if `myObject` isn't null, then the returned .get("time") object is.. thus `.get()` isn't throwing the NPE, but `toString()` is.. I'll modify the answer below.

Comment: Not a problem, thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `.get()` is throwing the the null pointer exception you could simply add another ternary case around it, for `.get()` to throw an NPE `myObject` must be `null`. Thus, this should work

```
time = myObject != null ? ((myObject.containsField("time")))?
       (myObject.get("time").toString().isEmpty())?"Empty":myObject.get("time").toString():"NA" : "null";
```

To account for the above comments, `.get` doesn't appear to be what is throwing the NPE, `.toString()` must be. Alter the code thusly:

```
time = myObject.containsField("time") ? myObject.get("time") != null ?
       (myObject.get("time").toString().isEmpty())?"Empty":myObject.get("time").toString():"NA" : "null";
```

The extra ternary block, will now check if the resulting `"time"` key results in a `null` pointer.

Comment: Its not working myObject is a DBObject. comparing myObject seems to be a not logical one as myObject will be having more than one columns to extract. I tried extracting it in the way you suggested but it is still failing